# How can I search for comments?

Tags: support, comments, search

Is it possible to search *just* for comments?

I tried putting `is:comment` in the search bar, but it apparently doesn't have any effect—the search still returned questions/answers.

Comment: Comments are specifically intended not to be long-lasting, so it's hardly surprising that no direct way is provided to search for them. What problem do you hope to solve this way, exactly?

Comment: [Search your comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76958/search-your-comments)

Comment: Depending on what you're looking to do, comments are in [the data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277952/1081494).